# Postgresql query across different tables with dynamic query

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get a customer id which can be placed in one of ten different tables. I don't want to hard code those table names to find it so I tried postgresql function as follows.

```
create or replace FUNCTION test() RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
 rec record;
BEGIN
  select id from schema.table_0201_0228 limit 1 into rec;
  return next rec;

  select id from schema.table_0301_0331 limit 1 into rec;
  return next rec;
END $$ language plpgsql;

select * from test() as (id int)
```

As I'm not familiar with postgresql function usage, how can I improve the code to replace 'schema.table1' with a variable, loop each table and return the result?

**NOTE: table names may change overtime. For example, table_0201_0228 and table_0301_0331 are for February and March respectively.**

Comment: Why don't you create a view that does a UNION over all those tables?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the table names may vary overtime based on date. For example, table_0205_0305, table_0405_0422, etc.

Comment: This looks like a very strange database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL for that:

```
create or replace FUNCTION test(p_schema text) 
  RETURNS table(id int)
AS $$
DECLARE
  l_tab record;
  l_sql text;
BEGIN
  for l_tab in (select schemaname, tablename 
                from pg_tables 
                where schemaname = p_schema) 
  loop
    l_sql := format('select id from %I.%I limit 1', l_tab.schemaname, l_tab.tablename);
    return query execute l_sql;
  end loop;
END $$ 
language plpgsql;
```

I made the schema name a parameter, but of course you can hard-code it. As the function is defined as `returns table`  there is no need to specify the column name when using it:

```
select *
from test('some_schema');
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your clear answer and quick reply:)

Comment: @EricHung: note that calling the function will fail completely if there is at least one table that does not have a column named `id`